# Explanation of ln derivative...

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

So we know that for example :

[image]

I'd like to know how do we get to this result based on:

[image]

I've been trying to do it for myself but I really have no idea how to get to the result starting.

Comment: are you willing to use the chain rule?

Comment: Anything... what I don't want to do it's just to memorize all the rules without knowing how to get to them.

Comment: Can we accept $\frac{d ln x}{dx} = \frac 1x$?  And can we accept the chain rule?

Comment: The derivative of $\log_e(x)$is $\frac1x$ and the derivative of $x^2-2$ is $2x$ so the chain rule makes it easy

Comment: " what I don't want to do it's just to memorize all the rules without knowing how to get to them. "  I suggest you practice being able to prove the the chain rule and product rule on demand until you absolutely trust it with your life.  Deriving this without the chain rule is pretty futile and of no value that I can see.

Comment: Can you use taylor series?

Comment: @ElliotG of course not, that's my given name, I'm from Mexico, several presidents were named liked myself.

Comment: @Adolf Thanks; my apologies. Just making sure, as one never knows these days.

Answer (score 2):

I'll show you an alternative way of evaluating deriving that $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

---

We know that if $f$ is differentiable in an interval $I$, with $f'(x) < 0$ or $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$, then $f$ has an inverse funcion $f^{-1}$which is defined and is differentiable on $f(I)$.

---

So let $f(x) = e^x$. Then $f$ is defined and differentiable in $\mathbb R$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb R,f'(x) > 0$, so there exists an inverse function defined and differentiable in $f(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R^+$, which is $f^{-1}(x) = \ln(x)$

We know that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$. If we differentiate from both sides we get:

$$\begin{align}
&(f^{-1})'(x)f'(f^{-1}(x)) = 1 \iff
\\
\\
&(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}
\end{align}$$

We know that $f'(x) = e^x$ so $f'(f^{-1}(x)) = x$. So we conclude that
$$\begin{align}
&(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{x} \iff
\\
\\
&\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}$$

Using then the chain rule you can get the derivative you want.

This is a common way of finding out derivatives for inverse functions.

Comment: You should mention that at this derivation already assumes $f^{-1} = \ln$ is differentiable at $x$.

Comment: We know that $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb R$ and $f'(x) > 0, \forall x \in \mathbb R$, so we conclude that there exists an inverse function $f^{-1}$ and that that inverse is differentiable in $\mathbb R^{+}$ @peek-a-boo

Comment: yup I'm aware of that. I was merely suggesting you add this explanation to your answer to make it more complete :)

Comment: Funny :) In my textbook they first derive the derivative of $\ln(x)$ and then they derive the derivative of $e^x$ using your approach. I guess giving any answers here is useless if you don't know the background of the person asking the question. E.g. I don't know too advanced stuff, and sometimes I ask for something simple, and I am given some proof which uses much more advanced apparatus (which maybe my textbook will derive 100 pages later). So... in a way this turns into pseudo-science as we're chasing our tails.

Comment: In my real analysis class that's how they introduced the derivatives of the inverse trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = \ln(x)$
then
$f(xy) = f(x)+f(y)
$
so
$f(x+h)
=f(x(1+h/x))
=f(x)+f(1+h/x)
$
and
$f(1) = 0
$
(since
$f(x)
=f(1*x)
=f(1)+f(x)
$)
so

$\begin{array}\\
f(x+h)-f(x)
&=f(1+h/x)\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
&=\dfrac{f(1+h/x)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{f(1+h/x)-f(1)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\dfrac{f(1+h/x)-f(1)}{h/x}\\
&\to\dfrac1{x}f'(1)
\qquad\text{as } h \to 0 \text{ if } f'(1) \text{ exists}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $f'(1)$ exists,
$f'(x) = \dfrac{f'(1)}{x}
$.

The natural log is the one
with $f'(1) = 1$.

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

If $ f(x) $ has the form
$$f(x)=\ln(g(x))$$
then

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac 1h\ln(\frac{g(x+h)}{g(x)})$$

$$\sim \frac 1h(\frac{g(x+h)}{g(x)}-1)$$

$$\sim \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\frac{1}{g(x)}$$

thus
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\frac{1}{g(x)}$$

or
$$f'(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$